# differentiation between form and upload Form in grails

Tags: forms, grails, gsp

I am little bit new to grails and I don't know the difference between **form** and **uploadForm** in grails, and if use upload form I can able send attachment file to grails controller. But not able to send attachment file when using form.Someone explain the difference of those form types.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best places to look is the documentation for both of these ([form](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Tags/form.html) and [uploadForm](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Tags/uploadForm.html)).

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Tags/uploadForm.html) regarding `uploadForm`:

> Identical to the standard form tag except that it sets the enctype
>   attribute to "multipart/form-data" automatically.